# Laravel 8: Construct Table

Tags: php, if-statement, html-table, datatable, datatables

How can I improve this code? The result is putting the number 1 at the end.

```
{{ ($user->SUPERUSER=='Y') ? print("<i class='fa fa-check-square'></i>") : print("<i class='fa fa-square'></i>") }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to do it like this:

```
{{ $user->SUPERUSER == 'Y' ? "<i class='fa fa-check-square'></i>" : "<i class='fa fa-square'></i>" }}
```

I usually do it like this for things like classes:

```
<i class="fa {{ $user->SUPERUSER == 'Y' ? 'fa-check-square' : 'fa-square' }}"></i>
```